# InvovationTargetException in a eclipse plugin-test

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp

I'm in a migration of my plugin kepler to luna. 
I compile with maven and I have a InvocationTargetException.
Like that :

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.OsgiSurefireBooter.run(OsgiSurefireBooter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.AbstractUITestApplication.runTests(AbstractUITestApplication.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Testable$1.run(E4Testable.java:73)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.surefire.util.NestedRuntimeException: Unable to create test class 'PLUG.plugin.common.service.ServiceManagerTest'; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PLUG.plugin.common.service.ServiceManagerTest cannot be found by PLUG.tests_1.5.2.qualifier
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultDirectoryScanner.loadClass(DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultDirectoryScanner.locateTestClasses(DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:78)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.scanClassPath(JUnit4Provider.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:83)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PLUG.plugin.common.service.ServiceManagerTest cannot be found by PLUG.tests_1.5.2.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.OsgiSurefireBooter$BundleClassLoader.findClass(OsgiSurefireBooter.java:181)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultDirectoryScanner.loadClass(DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:98)
    ... 15 more
```

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException means something else happened, in this case, a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PLUG.plugin.common.service.ServiceManagerTest cannot be found by PLUG.tests_1.5.2.qualifier

Comment: But ServiceManagerTest class is in project ...